# Moving elements around in a ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I'm trying to swap elements around in an ArrayList, but I don't know how to get the position of the items I want to sawp around because it's not a 2D array. I'm trying to use

```
Collections.swap(list, 3, 3-1);
```

But it doesn't work.

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
//System.out.println(list); //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Collections.shuffle(list);
// System.out.println(list); //[11, 5, 10, 9, 7, 0, 6, 1, 3, 14, 2, 4, 15, 13, 12, 8]

int[][] a2 = new int[4][4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0;  j< 4; j++) {


        a2[i][j] = list.get(i*4 + j);
      //  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a2)); //[[11, 5, 10, 9], [7, 0, 6, 1], [3, 14, 2, 4], [15, 13, 12, 8]]
    }
   //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a2)); //[[11, 5, 10, 9], [7, 0, 6, 1], [3,     14, 2, 4], [15, 13, 12, 8]]
 //  System.out.println();
}
for (int[] row : a2) {
System.out.print("[");
for (int i : row)
    System.out.printf("%4d", i);
System.out.println("]");
}
Collections.swap(list, 3, 3-1); //this is where im stuck

 }
```

I view this as a matrix, thats why I want to swap. How do co-ordinates in ArrayList work?

The output when you run this is:

```
[  10  15  12   7]
[   0   9   2   6]
[   4   3   1  11]
[   5   8  14  13]
```

I want to swap the elements up, down and sideways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm assuming**

1. You want to work with a matrix. That 4x4 square of numbers. Right?
2. You want to swap elements between positions in the matrix
3. You are using two ways of representation: `List<Integer>` and a `int[][]`

**How to swap with array**

Position `(i, j)` in your matrix is simply `a2[i][j]` so swaping between `(i, j)` and `(k, l)` is:

```
int aux = a2[k][l];
a2[k][l] = a[i][j]; // move value at first point to second point
a2[i][j] = aux; // move value at second poin tof irst point
```

**How to swap with list**

Position `(i, j)` in your list (because of the way you saved it) is `4*i+j`. So the indexes for the same points in the list are (as @aioobe said):

```
4*i+j
4*k+l
```

So you'd need to do this:

```
Collections.swap(list, 4*i+j, 4*k+l);
```

where 4 is the size of each row.

---

**Changing the approach**

If what you want is simply using that list for shuffling (because all the rest of the handling doesn't need a list but a matrix) I suggest: *use only List for that shuffling and forgetting*. How?

```
// at this point you only have a matrix: your `int a2[][]`
// and the List will only exist for the shuffling
// lets say that WIDTH HEIGHT exist and are int constants

List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>(WIDTH*HEIGHT);
for (int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
      list.add(a2[i][i]);

// now your integers are in the list and you can shuffle them
Collections.shuffle(tempList);

// now give the numbers back to the matrix (as on your previous code)
for (int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
      a2[i][i] = list.get(i*WIDTH+j);

// and you can forget your tempList
```

Even better you could make this a method:

```
private void shuffle(int[][] matrix, int width, int height) {
    List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>(width*height);
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
       for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
          list.add(matrix[i][i]);

    // now your integers are in the list and you can shuffle them
    Collections.shuffle(tempList);

    // now give the numbers back to the matrix (as on your previous code)
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
       for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
          matrix[i][i] = tempList.get(i*width+j);
}
```

Notice that tempList exists only when method executes.

Even better: create two methods for converting from matrix representation to list and viceversa. That way you can use them in other places (and your code is more readable). By example, you could refactor you code to initialize the ordered list and calling that method to convert it into an int matrix.

```
private List<Integer> toList(int[][] matrix, int width, int height) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(width*height);
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
       for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
          list.add(matrix[i][i]);
    return list;
}

private int[][] toMatrix(List<Integer> list, int width, int height) {
    // now give the numbers back to the matrix (as on your previous code)
    int[][] result = new int[height][];
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
       result[i] = new int[width];
       for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
          result[i][i] = list.get(i*width+j);
    }
    return result;
}

private int[][] shuffle(int[][] matrix, int width, int height) {
    List<Integer> tempList = toList(matrix, width, height);
    // now your integers are in the list and you can shuffle them
    Collections.shuffle(tempList);
    return toMatrix(tempList, width, height); 

}
```

**Notice** toMatrix and shuffle methods now return a new matrix!!

**Bottomline**

It's useful to see your code as small blocks of code each one doing some clearly defined task. The you can maintain the abstractions in your code and create methods (or even classes ;-) with useful names as I tried to do. Of course, as all things it comes with practice. Good luck.

**Disclaimer**

It's not usual to write all the solution but in order to learn it can be useful. So it is. Hope it's useful!

Comment: So if I say i = 0, j = 3 k = 2, l = 3 then Collections.swap(list, 4*i+j, 4*k+l); it would mean swap a2[0][3] with a2[2][3. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Your code initializes a list with numbers from 0 to 15. Then it creates a matrix (`int[][] a2`) of 4x4 and assign to each position the corresponding item in the list: 4*i+j. *You* are defining that mapping (and it's ok). So when you need to use the list instead of the matrix you need to remember what index in the list is related to each point.

Comment: One more thing... if you don't really need the list... you can get rid of it and use only the matrix. Why do you need the list? If you need the shuffle thing you could pass the numbers to a list, suffle it, get those shuffled numbers back to the matrix and forget the list... but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Yes that is what I want but I couldn't get it. How can do that? Do you n=mind posting it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure I understand your question, but as for the remark:

"I don't know how to get the position of the items"

use `ArrayList.add(int index, E element)`, this way you'll know that the element you just added is at poistion "index"

Comment: Ok. But looking at my code, will index be a number I want to add and what does E mean?

Answer (score 2):

To swap element at `i`,`j` with element at `k`,`l` you could do

```
Collections.swap(list, i*4+j, k*4+l);
```

Comment: Why you're using 'k' and 'l'? Do ArrayList work list 2D arrays?

Comment: You said *but I don't know how to get the position of the items*, so I showed you how to get the positions.

Comment: @ayokule: he's using (k,l) because you said you wanted to work with a 2D matrix, didn't you? ArrayList is a list so if you want to use it for holding 2D data you have to convert 2-coord points to a position in a list. Given your code it seems you are saving one row after another and its width is 4. So The 3d row (starting with 0) will be at indexes 2*4, 2*4+1, 2*4+2, 2*4+2, 2*4+3. Please be more clear in your question in order to people to help you.

Comment: OK. Sorry Im just a bit confused.

Comment: Lol. So should initialise k and l?

Comment: I think you need to provide an example of what it is you want to do. Which elements do you want to swap?

Comment: I want to saw 0 with any other number beside it, on top and under it.